# How to choose priors for bounds on circular truncated distributions?

Tags: monte-carlo, prior, circular-statistics, truncated-distributions

I am considering choices of priors for truncated distributions on a circle. Let's take the truncated normal distribution on the unit circle as an example. It has parameters $\mu \in [-\pi, \pi]$ and $\sigma$ for location and scale, respectively. But it also has parameters $a$ and $b$, which are the lower and upper bound respectively, which I have been tinkering with priors for without success. To protect $a<b$ I have reparametrized with $a := \alpha$ and $b := \alpha + \beta$ where $\beta$ requires a non-negativity constraint. Specifically I am getting a large number of divergences.

Below is an unsuccessful example which attempts to put uniform priors on $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I also tried a normal distribution for $\alpha$ and half-normal for $\beta$, since I had suspected the uniform distributions were the problem at first, but got similar divergence issues.

```py
import pymc as pm
import arviz as az
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from scipy.stats import truncnorm

# True parameter values
m = 10000
loc = 1
scale = 0.5
a = -2
b = 2

# Generate data
Y = truncnorm.rvs(a=a, b=b, loc=loc, scale=scale, size=m)

# Model
basic_model = pm.Model()

with basic_model:

    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    mu = pm.Normal("mu", mu=0, sigma=100)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal("sigma", sigma=2)
    alpha = pm.Uniform('alpha', lower=-np.pi, upper=np.pi)
    beta = pm.Uniform("beta", lower=0, upper=2*np.pi)


    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    Y_obs = pm.TruncatedNormal("Y_obs", mu=mu, sigma=sigma, lower=alpha, upper=alpha+beta, observed=Y)

with basic_model:
    idata = pm.sample(2000)
    az.plot_trace(idata, combined=True)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Here is the trace plot:

[image]

What sort of priors could I put on $\alpha$ and $\beta$, or $a$ and $b$, to get few-to-no divergences?

Comment: What is a Normal distribution on a circle?

Comment: @Xi'an In hindsight that could have been at least a couple of different things. I'll have to check my project notes. (I've enjoyed your blog, btw).